# How to access data returned from eosjs?

Tags: eosjs, react

I am struggling to find the right way to access the data in my react component.

This is my action creator. I save every row returned from the promise into an array

```
export function getBlocks(){
console.log("get blocks called");

var blocks = [];
eos.getTableRows(true, "blockboard", "blockboard", 
"board").then(function(data){
console.log("data in callback",data);

for(var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++){
  blocks.push(data.rows[i]);
}

});

  console.log("the blocks",blocks);

  return {
    type: GET_BLOCKS,
    payload: blocks
  };
}
```

This is my reducer:

```
export default function (state = [], action){
console.log('Action received', action);

    switch(action.type){
     case GET_BLOCKS:
        console.log("the received action", action.payload);
        return [...state, action.payload];
    }

return state;
}
```

In the component I receive the data but when I try to display it, it doesn't work. It gives me undefined when trying to access a specific row in the array.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Blocks extends Component {

renderBlocks(blockData){

 console.log("Data in renderBlocks Func",blockData);
 const alldata = blockData[0];
 console.log(alldata);


 if(alldata !== undefined){
   console.log("alldata ", alldata);
   return alldata.map(function(data){
     return(
       <div key={data.id}>
         <h3>{data.text}</h3>
       </div>);
   });

   }


   }

  render(){
   return (
      <div>
        <h2>Helloooo</h2>
        {this.renderBlocks(this.props.blocks)}
        <div></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps({blocks}){
  return {blocks};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Blocks);
```

These are the values for the console.logs that I get in the renderBlocs function.

[image: console.logs in renderBlock Function]

If I do something like blockData[0][0] to access the data, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

EDIT: 15.9.18 - 14:00 european time

I updated the renderBlocks function to reflect the answer.

```
renderBlocks(blockData){
console.log("Data that renderBlocks receives, blockData",blockData);
var alldata = blockData[0];
console.log("blockData[0]",alldata);


if(alldata !== undefined){
  const newdata = Object.keys(alldata).map(function(k){
    return alldata[k];
  });
  console.log("the new array looks like this", newdata);

  console.log(alldata);
}
}
```

This are the returned data objects:
[image: data in the browser]

I found a solution with the help of TeeAttack42. Thank you very much for your help!

### Solution

First I updated my action creator and reducers to reflect TeeAttack42s submission:

**action creator:**

```
export const getBlocks = async () => {
console.log("get blocks called");

let blocks = [];
await eos.getTableRows(true, "blockboard", "blockboard", 
"board").then(function(data){
    console.log("data in callback",data);
    if(data){
      blocks = data.rows;
    }


});

  console.log("the blocks",blocks);

  return {
    type: GET_BLOCKS,
    payload: blocks
  };
}
```

**reducer:**

```
export default function (state = [], action){
  console.log('Action received', action);

  switch(action.type){
    case GET_BLOCKS:
    console.log("the received action", action.payload);
    return [...state, ...action.payload];
  }

  return state;
}
```

Then I could do this in my component and it displayed the text:

```
  renderBlocks(blocks){
    if(blocks.length > 0){
      return blocks.map(function(data){
        return (<div key={data.id}>
                  <h3>{data.text}</h3>
                </div>);
      });
    }
  }

  render(){
    const {blocks} = this.props;
    console.log(blocks);

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Helloooo</h2>
        {this.renderBlocks(blocks)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**summary:**

I think that earlier approaches failed because of the async behaviour. This discussion helped me to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined. I was confused because console.log showed me something that maybe wasn't even there when I called it.

> The output of console.log(anObject) is misleading; the state of the object displayed is only resolved when you expand the > in the console. It is not the state of the object when you console.log'd the object.

By checking the blocks.length I make sure that the props.blocks is reiceived, then I can go on to show the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Actually your blocks are the `data.rows` so you can copy it. Also the `getTableRows` function is an async call. That's why we add async and await which will handle the method synchronosly.

```
export const getBlocks = async () => {
  console.log("get blocks called");

  let blocks = [];
  await eos.getTableRows(true, "blockboard", "blockboard", 
    "board").then(data => {
               console.log("data in callback", data);
               if(data){
                 blocks = data.rows;    
               }
             });

  console.log("the blocks",blocks);    
  return {
    type: GET_BLOCKS,
    payload: blocks
  };
}
```

Your reducer should copy the action.payload content, therefore use also a spread operator on it.

```
export default const receiveBlocks = (state = [], action) => {
    console.log('Action received', action);    
    switch(action.type){
     case GET_BLOCKS:
        console.log("the received action", action.payload);
        return [...state, ...action.payload];
    }    
    return state;
}
```

This uses an arrow function for rendering each Block as a component. I also fixed the object structure so that you can map over the `props.blocks` element easier.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Blocks extends Component {

  render(){
   const {blocks} = this.props;
   const Block = {data} =>  <div key={data.id}>
             <h3>{data.text}</h3>
          </div>)

   return (
      <div>
        <h2>Helloooo</h2>
        {blocks.map(item => <Block data={item}/>)}
        <div></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps({blocks}){
  return {blocks: ...blocks};
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Blocks);
```

---

**Obsolete - Just if alldata would be an object and not an array:**

I guess the problem lies in your object structure. Try to convert the object to a real array and not a JSON object with number values.

```
Object.keys(alldata).map(function(k) { return alldata[k] });
```

This will give you an array.

Another option could be to access the data by using a string and not a number like:

```
alldata["0"]
```

Comment: I also think the problem lies within my object structure but this solution doesn't work.
If I use the Object().map function on blockData it gives me an array where the first position is an array with the three elements.
If I use this on blockData[0] it gives me an empty array.
Using blockData["0"]["0"] also returns undefined.

Comment: Did you use the Object.keys(alldata) method? Because you want to iterate over the keys and not the object itself. Also you should try alldata = blockdata[0] and alldata["0"] or blockdata[0]["0"] because blockdata is an array and not an object. Therefore using a string as the first parameter won't work.

Comment: I used this:
    if(alldata !== undefined){
      const newdata = Object.keys(alldata).map(function(k){
        return alldata[k];
      });

Comment: edited my question to reflect your answer

Comment: Hmm ok, I just saw that alldata seems to be a simple a array and not an object. Sorry for that. What could be is that the map function does not work as expected... I will update my answer for a new possible solution.

Comment: I tried your new solution but it doesn't work.
I fixed the wrapping array tough. I have data in the array but when i try to access it like data[0] it always gives me undefined although data is being printed as an array one step before.

Comment: {   
 console.log("renderBlocks called", data);
    console.log("text of data", data[0]);
}
--------->
renderBlocks called []
text of data undefined

Comment: Hmm can you try to iterate over it with a simple for loop (< data.length) and print it?

Comment: data.length actually returns 0

Comment: i can also call data.valueOf("0").valueOf("0") and it returns the whole array

Comment: This is really strange, but I guess this is something that is more JavaScript related than eosjs. It could be some reference and scope issue. I recommend using `const` and `let` instead of `var`. I will try to code a new solution and update the answer. -------- Done please check if this works.

Comment: I edited my question with the solution. I tried your solution but it gave me an error saying each child should have unique key prop. But I realized that the code structure looked a bit different when I console.logged it. I then tried to access the text field again and it worked, so I figured a little bit different solution where I check for blocks.length. I think that assigning blocks = data.rows is also an important part of the solution.

Comment: Glad we solved this. I know that there are non blocking solutions for this as well. You should have a look at the redux thunk library there you can use action creators which whill take the dispatch function as parameter. With this dispatch function you can call a resolve action inside your promise.then function which will prevent the application from beeing blocked while waiting for the result of the api call. Good luck with your app.